# C# Advice about queueing

Tags: c#, queue, fifo, task-queue

I am seeking advice on a project I have been assigned and I'm looking to see how it's done "professionally," or any suggestions that can lead me to the right direction.

I have a server piece that accepts commands from clients and pushes out byte streams to a serial port. Although multiple clients can send commands to this server piece, our hardware only can handle one command at a time. My problem is with queueing in the software end.

I've implemented a `Queue<T>` helper class that also inserts data into a DataSet containing: the requesting client number, message data (byte array to write to serial port) and message type (command description). It will also list the queue commands in a DataGrid (on the Form). Probably not the way to go, but that's the only thing I can think of as far as retaining the requesting client and the data and showing, visually, the queue.

Where do I handle the processing of the queue? I thought about handling it on a custom event where if the DataGrid list changed (item added/removed), grab the first row of data in the DataSet and send it out to the serial port.

Any comments or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit: I forgot to add that it does require a response from the SerialPort as well, in order for the current executed command to be removed from the queue.

Comment: Surely if you're accepting data from clients you don't want to be modifying / entering it from the server's datagrid? Responding to a new datagrid item doesn't sound like a bad place to start

Comment: why did u implement the Queue<T> class? it s already there for u.

Comment: @Jon Cage: I'm just using the DataGrid to show the queue list (who's command is next in line).

Comment: @user177883: I implemented a helper class that also inserts it the data from the clients into a DataSet while I enqueue an item.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a database table to store the queue of commands.  The web app would add records to the queue and display the queue, then a separate process (such as a Windows service or console app) would request the next command from the database and send it to the serial port.

Answer (score 0):

Client requests can come in at any time, they'll probably be handled by some proxy class (WCF?) on its own thread/task. Then that thread/ task needs to coordinate with the task that's 'inside' the model actually processing the requests.

A good class to do this with is the [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx).

The server-thread will block until there's something in the collection to work on. It can then take it from the collection in a thread safe manner and process it. Doing it this way ensures that the requests can be accepted when they arrive, but they are processed on at a time.

The overall pattern to think of here is producer-consumer.

GJ

Answer (score 0):

If it is a high trasaction web application you might want to look at queueing system such as [MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [Service Broker Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345108%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) or [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/). Window service can then pick up the queued items and send it to serial port.